Create Hair angel-Ring with blender nodes
Hi I want to know if possible to achieve this effect with nodes in blender.
I have a texture .dds (i will upload the model and the texture at the end) that needs to act as a cubemap to create the hair angel ring. it should looks like the white part of the hair in the image. I also upload the video on how it behaves in respect to the camera 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLiQIvfKALQ
the problem I have is that when I tried using it as a cubemap it uses the mesh geometry and looks broken not as a smooth curve. I would like to know if there is a way to use that .dss texture and make it behave like the video. thanks in advance. 
Texture is called AngelRing.dds and model Model.fbx
This is how mine looks https://youtu.be/0bcRBQdqdis?si=eZ33p1tLduORoHhw
https://www.mediafire.com/file/rcfde2k3po33h4f/Hana_Susuki_%2528Casual%2529.rar/file


It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

What do you mean by "white" part of the hair? There are two different things that can be considered "white part" of the hair.

@DanielMöller hi the .dds cube map creates both rings the upper one and the lower one. Imagine it like just one part. I uploaded the model and the cube map too.

Could you provide a proper Blender file, instead of a collection of fbx, png and dds files ?

@StefLAncien yes i will do that right now

I think you’ll need to use the camera as a reference point, but how to get the ring to be the right shape with that… you could possibly also map the ring onto a smooth otherwise transparent sphere very close to the hair, and thus fake it. You would want to make sure it could only be seen over the hair though so it didn’t peek past the edges of her head to the sides.

@TheLabCat the problem with that solution is that besides the cubemap texture my model have a noise map texture to create those peaks on the halo ring and that uses the UV of the hair mesh for that noise texture. if I just project from the sphere I wouldn't be able to properly use that noise texture

I did not understand what you meant by peak:, but I meant for the sphere to be how you see the ring, sort of like if she was wearing an atom punk space helmet or goldfish bowl on her head, but the only part that was visible was the ring. In other words, fake the look of a shine on the hair by putting it above the hair.

You need to "pack" the resources in the blender file, otherwise no texture will appear.

@DanielMöller oh really sorry i just uploaded it
